# Threading and delegates - multithreading with class

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, delegates

I can make the below example to run on a different thread (for every function I'm calling) but I'm having a problem when I'm trying to combine it with Classes and delegation.

In the below example calling `threading.current_thread()` into the classes, I always get the same thread.

Any ideas why this is happening?

```
import threading
import time

class FirstClass(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, obj):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.obj = obj
        print(threading.current_thread())


    def compute(self, num_list):
        for n in num_list:
            time.sleep(0.2)
            print("Square: {}".format(n*n))
            self.obj.print_it(n)


class SecondClass(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        print(threading.current_thread())


    def print_it(self, n):
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print("Cube: {}".format(n*n*n))





t = time.time()
t1 = SecondClass()
t2 = FirstClass(t1)
t2.compute([1,2,3,4,5])

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()

print("Done in: {}".format(time.time()-t))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, few points before going to the solution which I got after trying quite a while: *(The working code is below, if you want to skip the explanation)*

(i) If you look at what [Thread.start()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start) does, you will see that it is mentioned that it

> arranges for `run()` method to be invoked in a separate thread of control.

So, what that means is, currently, without `run()` functions in your code for the thread classes, it is not going to invoke the other functions in a separate thread of control.

Hence the main thread is executing all of it. To understand this, place two of the run function definitions in each of your thread class:

```
def run(self):
    print(threading.current_thread())
```

and try running it. You will see that now, the separate threads are invoked.

(ii) So how would you go about calling your custom functions from `run()`?

When you look at [Thread.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.run)'s definition, it says

> The standard run() method invokes the callable object passed to the object’s constructor as the target argument, if any, with sequential and keyword arguments taken from the args and kwargs arguments, respectively.

So one way to do this is to you pass your arguments in the call `t1 = SecondClass(args = [1,2,3,4,5])` and receive and initialize it in `__init__` as:

```
def __init__(self, args):
```

Your `run()` function would then call your `compute` or `print_it`function like

```
def run(self):
    print_it(self, self.args)
```

(iii) But now, how are you going to call the other thread each time in the loop? You can only start a thread *once* and if you try giving a `self.object.run` for the `t1` thread in the loop each time, it is *not* going to go back to the thread's execution. It will continue that function in the same thread `t2`.

(iv) And also, how are you going to pass the current list value to `t1`, execute the cube root, and then jump back to `t2` and proceed with square of the next number?

For solving (iii) and (iv), you would need both a `Queue` (where the shared list can reside) and a synchronization mechanism that can safely execute one thread, then give control to the next, take it back again, etc.

Remember, threads share the same address space, so we should be careful to avoid race conditions, and only one thread can use the scheduler at a time. This is why a synchronization mechanism is needed.

Okay, so there are better ways to solve your problem (like just have two functions for square and cube and create two threads that call those functions directly without involving a class for each thread) but I have worked out a solution you can use to achieve your desired result.

**Here is the code (with comments as explanations):**

```
import threading, queue # need a queue for storing the shared values between threads
import time

class FirstClass(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, obj, args): # pass the extra args here
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.obj = obj
        self.args = args # initialize the args

    def run(self):
        compute(self, self.args)

def compute(self, args):
    num_list = args[0]
    lock = args[2] # lock object was passed in args[2]
    for n in num_list:
        lock.acquire_for('A') # acquire the lock
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print("Square: {}".format(n*n))
        print(threading.current_thread())
        args[1].put(n) # args[1] is the queue object, put number in queue
        lock.release_to('B') # release the lock to waiting thread

class SecondClass(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, args):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.args = args
    def run(self):
        print_it(self, self.args)

def print_it(self, args):
    lock = args[2]
    num_list = args[0]
    for a in num_list: # this is to iterate the exact number of times t2 iterates,
# so that the lock is released only by the thread that acquired it
# here we are alternating, so without this, the execution would stop
        lock.acquire_for('B') # acquire when t2 releases lock
        n = args[1].get() # args[1] is the queue object, get from queue
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print("Cube: {}".format(n*n*n))
        print(threading.current_thread())
        lock.release_to('A') # give back lock

class LockWithOwner:
    lock = threading.RLock() 

    owner = 'A'

    def acquire_for(self, owner):
        n = 0
        while True:
            self.lock.acquire()
            if self.owner == owner:
                break
            n += 1
            self.lock.release()
            time.sleep(0.001)
        print('Waited for {} to be the owner {} times'.format(owner, n))

    def release_to(self, new_owner):
        self.owner = new_owner
        self.lock.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = queue.Queue()
    t = time.time()
    lock = LockWithOwner()
    lock.owner = 'A'
    args_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
    t1 = SecondClass(args = (args_list, q, lock)) # pass the number list, queue & lock object
    t2 = FirstClass(t1, args = (args_list, q, lock))

    t1.start()
    t2.start()
    t1.join()
    t2.join()

    print("Done in: {}".format(time.time()-t))
```

Read more about the lock used here: [threading.RLock](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.RLock)

So, here what the lock class does is that, initially thread t1 can only start a job when owner is set to A, and thread t2 can only start a job when owner is set to B. Once thread calls `acquire_for`, it acquires the lock to scheduler, executes, and when thread calls `release_to`, it assigns the owner to the passed argument (the other thread) and releases the lock.

Your output on running the above code would be:

> `Waited for A to be the owner 0 times`
>
> `Square: 1`
>
> `<FirstClass(Thread-2, started 12360)>`
>
> `Waited for B to be the owner 1 times`
>
> `Cube: 1`
>
> `<SecondClass(Thread-1, started 204)>`
>
> `Waited for A to be the owner 1 times`
>
> `Square: 4`
>
> `<FirstClass(Thread-2, started 12360)>`
>
> `Waited for B to be the owner 1 times`
>
> `Cube: 8`
>
> `<SecondClass(Thread-1, started 204)>`
>
> `Waited for A to be the owner 1 times`
>
> `Square: 9`
>
> `<FirstClass(Thread-2, started 12360)>`
>
> `Waited for B to be the owner 1 times`
>
> `Cube: 27`
>
> `<SecondClass(Thread-1, started 204)>`
>
> `Waited for A to be the owner 1 times`
>
> `Square: 16`
>
> `<FirstClass(Thread-2, started 12360)>`
>
> `Waited for B to be the owner 0 times`
>
> `Cube: 64`
>
> `<SecondClass(Thread-1, started 204)>`
>
> `Waited for A to be the owner 1 times`
>
> `Square: 25`
>
> `<FirstClass(Thread-2, started 12360)>`
>
> `Waited for B to be the owner 1 times`
>
> `Cube: 125`
>
> `<SecondClass(Thread-1, started 204)>`
>
> `Done in: 3.1351969242095947`

Is this explanation clear to you? If you have any doubt, let me know. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
The comments are really helpful.
The logic is the same if i want to run the compute() on the main thread and print_it() on thread 1?

Comment: Your welcome, glad I could help :) Yes, the logic would be the same, you would need synchronization mechanisms because you start two separate blocks of executions (threads) so you would need a lock/semaphore to decide which thread gets to use the CPU at one time